# how to modify variables from the UI Thread by another Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-maps-markers

I've written a little application that shows some info downloaded from a MySQL DB on a GoogleMap (API v2).

Up until now, I was only asking my server and updating my map occasionally with an AssyncTask, but now I want my map to be updated dynamically and so I gotta make requests to my server "in real time". So I thought I should use a Thread that requests my DB on a loop.

I tried writing my own Thread as followed (simplified version) but maybe I did something wrong because it's not working:

```
public class loadMessages extends Thread {
    String messages[];
    public void run() {
        try{
            while(zoomActuel > 13){
 
                messages = myHttpRequest(); //simplified fonction to fetch info in my DB
 
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() { //i update my map by updating my ArrayList<Marker> called myMarkers
                        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                            myMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat[i], lng[i]))
                            .title(messages[i])));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea of how I should do it thanks in advance ;)

Comment: instead of `Thread` and `runOnUIThread` why you are not using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ?

Comment: How far do you get and what are you seeing with the debug flags in place in the surrounding break points?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : I'm not using AssyncTask because It's not reliable anymore for my need of a dynamic real time requests. It makes my app totally slowed.

Comment: @Jay Snayder: I haven't debugged it yet and I don't know where I should place the breakpoints

Comment: Could you elaborate on it not working? Is it not doing anything, actively crashing, etc?

Comment: well if I don't put it in a loop, it's not doing anything at all. I f I do, it makes my app crash on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these tutorials will help you.

You may use asynctask and update ui onProgressUpdate() or onPostExecute(), you can use runnableOnUiThread or thread with handler.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/